# Delete SMS from sent list in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am developing android app. I need to delete the SMS sent as soon as it is sent. I tried using following piece of code to delete the SMS but the sent box still shows this message in list, although it does not open up up when clicked.

```
public void sendSMS(View view){
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage("9XXXXXXXXX2", null, "CON", null, null);       
    Uri sentURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent/");                                 
    String[] reqCols = new String[] { "thread_id","_id", "address", "body" };
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();                                  
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(sentURI, reqCols, null, null, null);
    //Cursor cursor = cr.query(sentURI, reqCols, "address like ?", new String[]{"9673479788"}, null);
    String id =null;
    String thread_id =null;
    long threadId=0;
    int count;
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
              count = cursor.getCount();
              if (count > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                threadId = cursor.getInt(1);                      
                System.out.println("\n THREADID : "+String.valueOf(threadId));
                Uri thread = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent/" + threadId);
                //Uri thread = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent/" + threadId);
                getContentResolver().delete(thread, null, null);
              } else{
                  System.out.println("\n NOTHING DELETED");
            }
        } finally {
                  cursor.close();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n THREADID : "+St`enter code here`ring.valueOf(threadId));
}
```

I can still see the message in the sent box, although it does not open when clicked. Please help. Need to delete from the list of sent sms.

Comment: Are there any errors showing up in the log?

Comment: It does not show any exception. I checked the return from delete method. It is returning 0. My android version is 4.4.2